# how to eager load a has_and_belongs_to_many association in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a habtm association in a rails app using mongo / mongoid

```
class A
    has_and_belongs_to_many :bs, inverse_of: :as
end

class B
    has_and_belongs_to_many :as, inverse_of: :bs
end
```

and i want to

```
 A.where(...).includes(:bs)
```

but i get an error

```
 undefined method 'b_ids'
```

Is there a way to eager load habtms?

Thanks,
Kevin